# Can t upload reports from QBO

Tags: python-3.x, api, quickbooks-online

I m trying to fetch QBO reports with python I have this error:

intuitlib.exceptions.AuthClientError: HTTP status 400, error message: b'{"error_description":"The token is not an authorization code: actualTokenType=RefreshToken","error":"invalid_grant"}',

I tried to change auth code to refresh token and it is not working. I was able to connect to QBO for objects like invoices,...

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from intuitlib.enums import Scopes
import requests
import QBOConnector
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl'
auth_client = AuthClient(QBOConnector.CLIENT_ID, QBOConnector.CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, QBOConnector.environment )
url = auth_client.get_authorization_url([Scopes.ACCOUNTING])


auth_client.get_bearer_token(QBOConnector.TOKEN, realm_id=QBOConnector.CLIENT_ID)



auth_header = 'Bearer {0}'.format(auth_client.access_token)
headers = {
    'Authorization': auth_header,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

base_url = 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com'
url = '{0}//v3/company/{1}/query?query=ProfitAndLoss?&minorversion=4'.format(base_url,auth_client.realm_id)
print('Url')
print(url)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

print profil and loss report for a specific period of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl' # not using the redirection at the moment
ENV = QBOConnector.PROD_environment
REFRESH_TOKEN = QBOConnector.PROD_TOKEN # Refresh token needs to be added here (which will be generated from https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground)
COMPANY_ID = QBOConnector.PROD_COMPANY_ID #id of the company that we use in the example

# auth credentials to connect to the QBO account
auth_client = AuthClient(
        client_id = QBOConnector.PROD_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret = QBOConnector.PROD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        environment = ENV,
        redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI,
    )


# creating the client object to access the QBO account
client = QuickBooks(
        auth_client= auth_client,
        refresh_token= REFRESH_TOKEN,
        company_id= COMPANY_ID,
    )

# retrieving all customers for the above client object
customers = Customer.all(qb=client)

# printing all customer names on the console/shell
for customer in customers:
    print (customer)

# request authorization
auth_header = 'Bearer {0}'.format(auth_client.access_token)
headers = {
    'Authorization': auth_header,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

base_url = 'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com'

# --- trial Balance
url = '{0}//v3/company/{1}/reports/TrialBalance?end_date=2019-09-30&minorversion=4'.format(base_url,
                                                                                           QBOConnector.PROD_COMPANY_ID)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```